# How to `kill -HUP` apps in macOS 12+?

Tags: memory, launchd, monterey, restart, launch-services

Long ago it was relatively simple to kill and start some apps and processes in macOS by issuing a `killall -HUP PROCESS_NAME`. It seemed that most apps and processes respected the `-HUP` signal, but that's no longer been the case for quite a few years now and it doesn't work for my use case either as outlined:

I have a particularly troublesome, but necessary, LaunchAgent started app (`macOS InstantView.app` from Silicon Motion) that controls external displays attached to a USB hub. I'm finding that it's got a memory leak that causes it to grow about 250mb in memory usage per hour and is just enough to not easily notice, but then you find it really causing problems after a day or two depending on your system resources.

(And yes, I've reported the problem to the manufacturer, but they seem to function akin to molasses stuck out in the cold of a northern Canadian winter.)

I'd like to kill it every few hours, but I need to rapidly restart it so that it doesn't completely bugger up my app arrangement on the displays that are attached to it.  I was hoping to `killall -HUP` it, but it's just not restarting.

Any ideas on doing a rapid kill/start of something like this?

UPDATE:

The following KIND OF works (albeit very clunky) in my case since I can't seem to get the LaunchAgent to trigger properly as it normally should:

```
killall -9 "macOS InstantView" ; "/Applications/macOS InstantView.app/Contents/MacOS/macOS InstantView"&
```

This causes it to restart essentially right away when executing in the shell.

Comment: Maybe use `-TERM` or `-KILL` instead?

Comment: `HUP` is the hang up signal. An interactive shell will terminate, but most other processes won't (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251195/difference-between-less-violent-kill-signal-hup-1-int-2-and-term-15 for details). Use `TERM` to give the process time to close open files and finish other clean up tasks, and use `KILL` to terminate the process immediately. I'd recommend that you use `TERM` first, then `KILL`.

Comment: Hum, not sure how this was misinterpreted: I was using `-HUP` as an illustrative point. In reality I want to efficiently restart a process. Killing is fine, but that's not what I want alone, I have to restart it rapidly. `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.smiUsbDisplay.macOSInstantView.loginscreen.plist` doesn't work (I would follow that with a `load`, but again, doesn't work to even unload it in the first place), so I'm trying to figure out options to handle this kill/start.

Comment: Right now the question asks how to kill -HUP. If this is not what you wanted it might help to rewrite the question to focus on expected outcome instead.

Comment: @nohillside `kill -HUP` is a two step process by its nature and anyone who understands what `-HUP` is should likewise understand that it is a kill/stop + restart. That is therefore my question and what should be understood by those "in the know" (and to whom this question is intended). Therefore my succinct title, if one were to expand it could be "How does one stop and restart a process rapidly in macOS with the same effect as what `killall -HUP PROCCESS_NAME` might function traditionally?"

Comment: You got comments from two people who didn‘t „get it“, so a revision might help to broaden the audience. From what I gather you ask about how to quickly restart a process launched by launchd (so mentioning kill or HUP seems to send people down the wrong path).

Comment: What about a script to kill, delay and then start? so the kill and start are separated by 10 seconds for example.